# Basic pattern: Populate a template with JSON from an external URL in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am struggling to figure out the basic pattern for populating a template with data from a call to an external API in Meteor.

#### These are the elements in play

1. A fresh Meteor project, created by running `meteor create monkeyproject`
2. The URL of an external API that returns a JSON array. Let's say it's `example.com/api/getmonkeys`. It returns an array of monkeys, each with a different `name`.
3. A Handlebar template called `monkeyTemplate` with an `{{#each}}` loop. Let's say it's this:

   ```
   <template name="monkeyTemplate">
       {{# each monkeys}}
           One of our monkeys is named {{name}}. <br>
       {{/each}}
       <input type="button" id="reload" value="Reload monkeys" />
   </template>
   ```

#### What I want to happen

- When the page loads fill `monkeyTemplate` with monkeys from our external URL.
- When the user clicks the button, call the external URL again to reload the monkeys.

#### The question

**What is a standard pattern for doing the above in Meteor?** At the risk of cluttering up the question, I'll include some starting points, as I understand them.

- We can populate the template with whatever we return from our `Template.monkeyTemplate.monkeys` function. *How do we fill it with content from an external URL, given that the page will load before the external request is finished?*
- We can get our JSON by using `Meteor.HTTP.call("GET", "http://example.com/api/getmonkeys", callback )`. *Where do we put this request, and what do we put into our callback function in this situation?*
- We can control what happens on the server side and what happens on the client side by using the `Meteor.isServer`/`Meteor.isClient` conditions, or by putting our code into files called `client` and `server` folders. *What code needs to be on the server side vs. the client side?*
- We determine what happens when the button is clicked by attaching a function to  `Template.monkeyTemplate.events['click #reload']`. *What goes into our callback function in this situation?*

I will refrain from cluttering up the question with my crappy code. I am not looking for anyone to write or rewrite an application for me—I am just looking for the guidelines, standard patterns, best practices, and gotchas. Hopefully this will be instructive to other beginners as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the "standard" template, but it serves the purpose pretty well.

- Set up two data helpers for the template, `monkeys` and `loading`. First one will display the actual data once it's fetched, the latter will be responsible for notifying user that the data is not yet fetched.
- Set up a dependency for these helpers.
- In `created` function of the template, set `loading` helper to true and fetch the data with `HTTP` call.
- In the callback, set the template data and fire the dependency.

**html**

```
<template name="monkeys">
   {{#if loading}}
       <div>Loading...</div>
   {{/if}}
   {{#if error}}
       <div>Error!</div>
   {{/if}}
   {{#each monkeys}}
       <div>{{name}}</div>
   {{/each}}
   <div><button class="monkeys-reloadMonkeys">Reload</button></div>
</template>
```

**js**

```
var array = null;
var dep = new Deps.Dependency();
```

```
Template.monkeys.created = function() {
    reloadMonkeys();
};

Template.monkeys.events({
    'click .monkeys-reloadButton': function(e,t) {
         reloadMonkeys();
    };
});

var reloadMonkeys = function() {
    array = null;
    dep.changed();
    HTTP.get('http://example.com/api/getmonkeys', function(error, result) {
        if(!error && result) {
            array = result;
        } else {
            array = 0;
        }
        dep.changed();
    });
};
```

```
Template.monkeys.monkeys = function() {
    dep.depend();
    return array ? array : [];
};

Template.monkeys.loading = function() {
    dep.depend();
    return array === null;
};

Template.monkeys.error = function() {
    dep.depend();
    return array === 0;
};
```